# CSS Дочерний элемент со свойствами float и clear смещается вниз

Tags: css, float

Не могу найти объяснение данного результата:
Имеется родительский элемент *.p* в нем три инлайновских дочерних элемента(.p 50%, .c1 25%, .c2 25%), два последних *.с1* и *.с2* из которых имеют свойство *float:right*, то есть будут идти друг за другом, если поместятся в строку, все друг к другу впритык. Но если поставить последнему элементу *.с2* свойство *clear:both*, то он сместится под *.с1* - логично. Дальше, если сделать так, что у *.с2* ширина не 25% и допустим 40%, то *.с2* смещается не под *.с1*, а под элемент *.con*. Почему, ведь у *.с2* ещё есть место до границ элемента *.con*?
Такое ощущение будто *.с2* свойством *clear:both* снимает всего лишь обтекание, а место резервируется в строчке наряду с элементом *.с1*

https://jsfiddle.net/v7gonnj9/

```css
.p {
  width: 50%;
}
.con {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
.c1 {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
}
.c2 {
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: blue;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='p'>
  <span class='con'></span><span class='c1'></span>
  <span class='c2'></span>
</div>
```

нужно шоб було как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы лучше картинку нарисуйте в паинте : что хотите получить

Comment: у вас сейчас классы в коде не совпадают с классами в описании вопроса

Comment: llexxl всё совпадает : есть родитель .p > .con +  .c1 + .c2 просто переноса нету между .con и .c1

Comment: в общем косяк вот он : .con / 50% + .c1 /25% + .c2 / 40% = 115% а родитель для них всего 100% но не 115%

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/v7gonnj9/1/  вот ваш пример

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вам флоаты? Используйте абсолютное позиционирование.

```css
.p {
  width:50%; 
  position:relative
}
.con {
  width:50%; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: green; 
  display: inline-block;
 }
.c1 {
  width:25%;
  height: 50px; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
.c2 {
  width:40%; 
  height: 50px; 
  box-sizing:border-box; 
  background-color: blue;
  position:absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='p'>
<span class='con'></span>
<span class='c1'></span>
<span class='c2'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ваша реализация конечно жесть))

Comment: Можете аргументировать? Что плохого в абсолютном позиционировании?

Comment: а при переполнении верхнего правого блока что будет с нижним правым блоком ?

Comment: Один на другой наедет естественно. Но если требуется правильное позициорировние элементов относительно друг друга, то тут требуется правильная разметка(пометить оба правых блока в отдельный контейнер). Но насколько я понял из вопроса этого не требовалось.

Comment: Андрей, на самом деле так у меня щас и работает )
Но хотелось бы объяснения данного феномена с флотами, в инете не нашёл

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.clear,.clear:after,.clear:before{
  content:''; display:block; clear:both; 
}
.left_content{
  width:50%;
  height:300px;
  min-height:300px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
.left,.right{
  float:left;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.left{
  width:60%;
  height:100%;
  background:green;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
}
.right{
  width:40%;
  height:100%;
  background:#fff;
}
.right_child_1{
  width:60%;
  float:right;
  min-height:100px;
  background:yellow;
}
.right_child_2{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  background:lightblue;
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left_content clear">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"> 
     <div class="right_child_1"></div>
     <div class="right_child_2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

У вас проблема в % соотношении от потомков  `<div class="p"><p>` который для них `100%`. А что  получается .con / 50% + .c1 /25% + .c2 / 40% = 115%   а родитель для потомков **100%** а в сумме получается **50+25+40=115** вот и блок падает в низ на fiddle я показал пример :
https://jsfiddle.net/atlanta/v7gonnj9/1/  для правильного **percent**

Comment: вопрос не в том что он падает вниз, а вопрос в том почему он падает под .con, а не под .с1, ведь на второй строчке под .с1 места хватает

Comment: у элемента .с2 нет соседа, потому как у него свойство clear: both

Comment: clear: both или clear: right в нашем случае без разницы. Вы два блока обвернули .с1 и .с2 в один - это одно из решений, о котором и так понятно. Я пытаюсь понять, почему блок .с2 находится под .con, а не под .с1, ведь будучи находясь на второй строке под .с1 места до .con хватает. Ощущение такое, что _clear_ визуально смещает на следующую строчку, но физически находится на позиции как без свойства clear